# How to connect SQL Server x64 to Progress, using OE10.2Bx86?

Tags: openedge, progress-db

```
OS: Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise - 64-bit - En.Us
DBMS: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard - Windows - 64-bit - En.Us
ODBC Driver: Progress OpenEdge 10.2B - Windows - 32-bit - En.Us
```

I don't have the related ODBC Driver in 64-bit version.

Do I have options to connect, to the Progress Database, using Query, or Linked Server? If I have, what are my options?

Thank you all!!!

Answer (score 0):

The Progress ODBC drivers can be downloaded from the Progress site. Log in with your ID on http://www.progress.com/esd/

Contact support if you can't find them.

There's also a product called "Pro2" replication that can "almost live" replicate from Progress to for instance SQL server if you have that demand. It might only be offered from 11.X and forward, I'm unsure about that.

https://www.progress.com/openedge/features/openedge-pro2/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had looked at the download site of Progress, but I saw that there is not available a 64-bit version. The problem is that my SQL Server is 64-bit and I need to connect on the Progress database, using a 32-bit ODBC driver. Is there a way, even if needed to use a thirdy part tool?

Comment: There should bi a 64-bit driver available. Maybe you need to contact support. It does seem that you cant have both 32 and 64-bit drivers though. http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-add-a-64-bit-ODBC-driver-for-OpenEdge-10-2B-ODBC-connections-to-a-64-bit-Windows-machine-that-already-has-a-32-bit-OpenEdge-10-2B-installation-installed

Answer (score 0):

If you were to download one of the 11x 64bit Client Access bundles, these will quite happily connect to a 32bit 10.2b database.

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P88405

Answer (score 0):

You do have options. Fundamentally, you can use our [Multi-Tier ODBC Drivers for Progress](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-progress-mt/) (versions 6.x to 10.x) to connect a 64-Bit ODBC Compliant application to a 32-Bit Progress RDBMS. This 64-Bit client to 32-Bit server bridging is achieved as a result of the [RDBMS-independent communications layer](http://uda.openlinksw.com/images/aodbcmtprog.gif) used by these drivers.